# How to care for cilantro indoors

Tags: cilantro

I've tried to grow cilantro from seed, and also I've purchased cilantro already grown and kept it on my windowsill. In the case of the cilantro I've grown from seed, it grows the first set of leaves and then promptly dies. In the case of the store-bought cilantro, I think my best track record was keeping the cilantro alive for 3 days before it keeled over. (For what it's worth, I have a very good track record with other plants!!)

I've heard that cilantro is pretty tough and doesn't mind the occasional under- or over-water. I've tried watering every day. I've tried watering only when it's very dry (if it lives long enough to dry out). I've kept it in full sun, part shade, and full shade. Nothing has worked! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what kind of soil are you using?

Comment: Potting soil I purchased at the garden store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never had issues growing cilantro inside. Here are a few things to check on

Heat - Cilantro does not do well with heat. Put a thermometer on or near the pot. cilantro prefer early and late day sun, make sure it shaded during the heat of the day.

Planting Bowl - at least 18 inches wide and 8 to 10 inches deep.

Planting - Put the seeds in the soil and then cover them with about a 1/4 inch layer of soil. I know a friend that puts her's in sand until they germinate.

Soil - fast-draining potting soil. Mist with water at first, Cilantro are kind of delicate don't dump water on them fill slowly around the edges.